# Spark to subscribe to ActiveMQ or Mosquitto MQTT broker

Tags: mqtt, apache-spark

I want to subscribe Spark to the ActiveMQ or Mosquitto MQTT broker. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

A more recent pull request and code for MQTT adapter for Spark Streaming in apache incubator spark repository is here, see merge commit https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/dd659642e77dca9a123178f98e399720127454c2

Comment: This updated pull request was just merged, so MQTT support will be included in the Spark 0.9.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

[There's a pull request](https://github.com/mesos/spark/pull/862) to add a MQTT input source to Spark Streaming.  We decided not to accept this PR right now (we wanted to judge the demand for MQTT before supporting it), but you should be able to take that PR's code and put it your own package.

Also, check out the [Spark Streaming Custom Receivers](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html) guide for information on writing custom input receivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom spark streaming receiver.Which allows you to read from any sources